# How to debug the code in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a function like this in one of my classes

```
using MFDBAnalyser;

namespace PrimaryKeyChecker
{
    public class PrimaryKeyChecker : IMFDBAnalyserPlugin
    {
        public string RunAnalysis(string ConnectionString)
        {
            return "Srivastava";
        }
    }
}
```

and when I call the `RunAnalysis(string ConnectionString)` method in another class like this

```
namespace MFDBAnalyser
{
    public interface IMFDBAnalyserPlugin
    {
        string RunAnalysis(string ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Then how can I check that the RunAnalysis is whether returning Srivastava or not....

Comment: @Daniel: Some people may not have the level of knowledge you do, hence why they come to this website.  They are learning and they come here for advice, not nasty comments.

Comment: @Ardman - I agree @Daniels comments are out of order

Comment: @Daniel - That's not very helpful is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add System.Diagnostic.Debugger.Break(), when you will run your application in Visual studio the debugger will stop at that line. You will then be sure that "Srivastava" is returned.

```
using MFDBAnalyser;

namespace PrimaryKeyChecker
{
    public class PrimaryKeyChecker : IMFDBAnalyserPlugin
    {
        public string RunAnalysis(string ConnectionString)
        {
            System.Diagnostic.Debugger.Break() 
            return "Srivastava";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you could. Or you could just set a breakpoint by clicking in the margin of the editor on the line you want to halt execution. The line will highlight in a dark red (unless you've changed your color scheme). For quick and dirty testing, this is a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Test()
{
    IMFDBAnalyserPlugin myClass = new PrimaryKeyChecker();
    var result = myClass.RunAnalysis("you connection string");
}
```

The result should be equal to "Srivastava"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `RunAnalysis` it within an **interface**.

Interfaces are merely provide a definition - in this case what `RunAnalysis` should look like in a class that implements the interface (`IMFDBAnalyserPlugin`)